# creating a transparent overlay using OpenCV in python

Tags: python, opencv

So I have two images, one is a white image with a blurred spot and other is a image of a street(taken from KITTI dataset). I want to blend both the white image with blurred spot and street image such that the whiteness doesnt appear while blending.\

In the first image below, you can see a translucent gray spot. This I achieved by making a copy of the street image and then drawing a circle on it using cv2.circle function. This i blended it back with the original image and controlled the transparency of the circle.

In place of the circular spot, I want the blurred spot in the white image to appear with transparency. How can this be achieved?

[image: street image]

[image: white image with blurred spot]

When i do normal blending the white shade also appears. I tried converting into RGBA image and then blending but didnt work. Any idea how this could be achieved?

Comment: Create a float mask where the fully transparent region is 0 and the other regions go from 0 to 1, the bigger the less transparent. Then blend result = mask*overlay + (1-mask)*original_image

Comment: Thanks..that seems a good idea.. but could you maybe elaborate a lil more with the final implementation of blending..i couldnt quite get that